# How to find select option position?

Tags: jquery, indexing, html-select

I'm trying to find an option's index.

For example, I would like to get 1 when I run the following fake code

JS:

```
$("#test[value='USD']").index() ?
```

HTML:

```
<select id='test'>
  <option value='CNY'>CNY</option>
  <option value='USD'>USD</option>
</select>
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You were very close, you want to use [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) on the `option` element, not the `select`:

```
var i = $("#test option[value='USD']").index();
```

[Gratuitous live example](http://jsbin.com/icomad)

Note that this will break if your `select` contains `optgroup` elements. If so, you'll want to pass `'option'` into `index`:

```
var i = $("#test option[value='USD']").index('option');
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/icomad/2) (I changed the position so it's the 4th element for that example)

Answer (score 0):

from [`Reference`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
.index() can take a DOM node and returns an index, 
 We get back the zero-based position of the list item:
```

Answer (score -2):

Im sure there is a straight forward way of counting the index in such occasions i just can't remember it right now, but you could try creating a function that loops between each values, and raises a counter +1 each time, until you get $("#test").val("USD")

Comment: See @T.J.'s answer to refresh your memory ;)