# Multiple selection with checkbox multi level by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I want to implement drop-down list with multiple group selection checkbox but could not find the exactly one. It is something similar to this : [multiple select](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#with-optgroups1). But unfortunately, mine has multi level parent and child as this image : [image]

This is the structure of the code :

```
 <select id="ms" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Parent 1</option>
            <option value="2">    > Child 1</option>
            <option value="2">    > Child 2</option>
        <option value="4">Parent 2</option>
        <option value="5">Parent 3</option>
            <option value="2">  > Child 1</option>
            <option value="2">  > Child 2</option>
            <option value="2">  > Sub Parent 3</option>
                <option value="2">  >-> Child 1</option>
                <option value="2">  >-> Child 2</option>
 </select>
```

I don't use `<optgroup>` because I don't want to modify the structure of the code since all the code of the dropdown list is the structure that received from server side.

- When all the children are selected, the parent would be selected too.
- When all the children are selected, there should be only parent's name that showed in the selected filed.
- If one of children is deselected , then the parent would be deselected too.
- The sub level should work as the 1st level as well.

Is there any recommend plugin jquery for this?

Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: "*Is there any recommend [jQuery plugin] for this?*" - we [don't do shopping](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/); if you've attempted something then please show that attempt and explain what went wrong. If all you want us to do is suggest an external resource then this question is off-topic and should be deleted. [softwarerecs.se] *might* help you out, but do read their help pages before posting the question there.

Comment: How is parent/child relationship supposed to be determined? No plugin will work if you can't establish that relationship using some value parsing convention or data attributes

Answer (score 0):

This is totally messed up, but you can always try to do this way:

1. Find the posision of check option by getting its position on a list like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773123/how-to-find-select-option-position)
2. Make all `if/else` statments which requires:

   - Get the possition of my parent
   - *and if all my siblings are checked*: check my parent and get rig of all other scopes